# zf2 segment route catching id on last position

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

I want my url route to have a dynamic part and to end up on the same page not matter if whatever I have in the middle part of my URL.

E.g.:

`/en/the-old-category/the-old-name/pid/123123123`

`/en/the-new-category/now-in-a-sub-category/the-new-name/pid/123123123`

Should both get caught by the same controller/action (which will issue the pertinent 301/302 if necessary).

My current router contains:

```
'router'       => [
    'routes' => [
        'blog' => [
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => [
                'route'         => "/[:language]",
                'constraints'   => [
                    'language' => '[a-z]{2}'
                ],
                'defaults'      => [
                    'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\List',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    'language'   => 'en'
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => [
                    'detail'  => 'segment',
                    'options' => [
                        'route'       => '/:path/pid/:postid',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'path'   => '.+',
                            'postid' => '\d{1,10}'
                        ],
                        'defaults'    => [
                            'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\List',
                            'action'     => 'detail'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

But it's not working.
`/` and `/en` are being caught properly, but subroutes like the ones I proposed earlier, are not.

Am I in the right path to do what I want to do? Should I write a regex route instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since between the first and the last part of my URL I need to have a variable number of segments, I can't do this with a `segment` route, but I was able to manage it with a `regex` route, configured as follows:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'blog' => [
            'type'         => 'regex',
            'options'      => [
                'regex'         => "/(?<language>[a-z]{2})?",
                'spec'          => "/%language%",
                'defaults'      => [
                    'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\List',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ],
            'child_routes' => [
                'detail' => [
                    'type'    => 'regex',
                    'options' => [
                        'regex'    => '/(?<path>.+)/pid/(?<postid>\d+)$',
                        'spec'     => '/%path%/pid/%postid%',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\List',
                            'action'     => 'detail'
                        ]
                    ]
                ] 
            ] 
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Just FYI the language route could have remained a segment route - child routes do no need to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

`.+` won't match `/` because segment routes split the path on `/` before applying constraints. To make your route work you'll need something like `/:path/:foo/pid/:postid`. A regex route might also work.

Comment: Please don't add code to my answer as if it was posted by me - I've rolled back the edit. That code should have been posted as a separate answer which you could have then accepted.

Comment: My answer explained why what you're trying to do wasn't working and provided a possible solution (which it turns out didn't help you because of additional information you then provided). I'm sorry that you feel this was "almost worthless", but with your new answer we now have an answered question, which will may help others with a similar problem. IMO the ability to edit other people's questions/answer is mainly for improving readability (e.g. typos, formatting).